# Python 2.7 ProcessPoolExecutor throwing IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am streaming data into a class in chunks.  For each chunk of data, two different types of np.convolve() are executed on the same ProcessPoolExecutor.  The type of convolve that was called is determined by a return variable. 
 The order of the data must be maintained, so each future has an associated sequence number.  The `output` function enforces that only data from contiguous futures is returned (not shown below).  From what I understand I am properly calling the `ProcessPoolExecutor.shutdown()` function, but I am still getting a `IOError`:

The errors is:

```
$ python processpoolerror.py 
ran 5000000 samples in 3.70395112038 sec: 1.34990982265 Msps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
    send(obj)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Sorry it's a bit long, but I have pruned this class down as much as possible while keeping the error.  On my machine `Ubuntu 16.04.2` with a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz` the paired down code always gives this error.  In the non-pruned version of this code, the Broken pipe occurs 25% of the time.

If you edit line `78` to `True`, and print during the execution, the error is not thrown.  If you reduce the amount of data on line `100`, the error is not thrown.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time


def _do_xcorr3(rev_header, packet_chunk, seq):
    r1 = np.convolve(rev_header, packet_chunk, 'full')
    return 0, seq, r1

def _do_power3(power_kernel, packet_chunk, seq):
    cp = np.convolve(power_kernel, np.abs(packet_chunk) ** 2, 'full')
    return 1, seq, cp

class ProcessPoolIssues():

    ## Constructor
    # @param chunk_size how many samples to feed in during input() stage
    def __init__(self,header,chunk_size=500,poolsize=5):
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size  ##! How many samples to feed

        # ProcessPool stuff
        self.poolsize = poolsize
        self.pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(poolsize)
        self.futures = []

        # xcr stage stuff
        self.results0 = []
        self.results0.append((0, -1, np.zeros(chunk_size)))

        # power stage stuff
        self.results1 = []
        self.results1.append((1, -1, np.zeros(chunk_size)))

        self.countin = 0
        self.countout = -1

    def shutdown(self):
        self.pool.shutdown(wait=True)


    ## Returns True if all data has been extracted for given inputs
    def all_done(self):
        return self.countin == self.countout+1

    ## main function
    # @param packet_chunk an array of chunk_size samples to be computed
    def input(self, packet_chunk):
        assert len(packet_chunk) == self.chunk_size

        fut0 = self.pool.submit(_do_xcorr3, packet_chunk, packet_chunk, self.countin)
        self.futures.append(fut0)

        fut1 = self.pool.submit(_do_power3, packet_chunk, packet_chunk, self.countin)
        self.futures.append(fut1)

        self.countin += 1


    # loops through thread pool, copying any results from done threads into results0/1 (and then terminating them)
    def cultivate_pool(self):
        todel = []

        for i, f in enumerate(self.futures):
            # print "checking", f
            if f.done():
                a, b, c = f.result()
                if a == 0:
                    self.results0.append((a,b,c))  # results from one type of future
                elif a == 1:
                    self.results1.append((a,b,c))  # results from another type of future
                todel.append(i)

        # now we need to remove items from futures that are done
        # we need do it in reverse order so we remove items from the end first (thereby not affecting indices as we go)
        for i in sorted(todel, reverse=True):
            del self.futures[i]

            if False:  # change this to true and error goes away
                print "deleting future #", i

    # may return None
    def output(self):

        self.cultivate_pool()  # modifies self.results list

        # wait for both results to be done before clearing
        if len(self.results0) and len(self.results1):
            del self.results0[0]
            del self.results1[0]
            self.countout += 1

        return None


def testRate():
    chunk = 500

    # a value of 10000 will throw:  IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    # smaller values like 1000 do not
    din = chunk * 10000

    np.random.seed(666)
    search = np.random.random(233) + np.random.random(233) * 1j
    input = np.random.random(din) + np.random.random(din) * 1j

    pct = ProcessPoolIssues(search, chunk, poolsize=8)

    st = time.time()
    for x in range(0, len(input), chunk):
        slice = input[x:x + chunk]
        if len(slice) != chunk:
            break
        pct.input(slice)
        pct.output()

    while not pct.all_done():
        pct.output()

    ed = time.time()
    dt = ed - st

    print "ran", din, "samples in", dt, "sec:", din / dt / 1E6, "Msps"

    pct.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testRate()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz, `futures==3.1.1`, `numpy==1.13.1`)

Comment: please post your library version,and try python3.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you're exceeding the buffer size of the pipe when you try sending in larger chunks at once.

```
def _do_xcorr3(rev_header, packet_chunk, seq):
    r1 = np.convolve(rev_header, packet_chunk, 'full')
    return 0, seq, r1

def _do_power3(power_kernel, packet_chunk, seq):
    cp = np.convolve(power_kernel, np.abs(packet_chunk) ** 2, 'full')
    return 1, seq, cp
```

the values r1 and cp are very large because you are convolving with the square of the chunks.

Hence, when you try to run this with larger chunk sizes, the buffer of IO Pipe can't handle it. Refer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer) for clearer understanding.

As for the second part of the question,

```
if False:  # change this to true and error goes away
                print "deleting future #", i
```

Found this in the py3 docs:

> 16.2.4.4. Reentrancy
>   Binary buffered objects (instances of BufferedReader, BufferedWriter, BufferedRandom and BufferedRWPair) are not reentrant. While reentrant calls will not happen in normal situations, they can arise from doing I/O in a signal handler. If a thread tries to re-enter a buffered object which it is already accessing, a RuntimeError is raised. Note this doesn’t prohibit a different thread from entering the buffered object.
>   The above implicitly extends to text files, since the open() function will wrap a buffered object inside a TextIOWrapper. This includes standard streams and therefore affects the built-in function print() as well.